# extend a value to fill missing values

Tags: r, na

I want to fill the missing value from the first non-missing value and extend it:

```
user   action
    1       NA
    1        2
    1       NA
    1       NA 
    1        3
    1       NA
    2       NA
    2       NA
    2        1
    2       NA
```

my desired output:

```
       user   action
        1        0
        1        2
        1        2
        1        2 
        1        3
        1        3
        2        0
        2        0
        2        1
        2        1
```

basically, based on the the `user` I want to fill NA values. It starts from 0 and when reach the next value, it extend and replace `"NA"`s till next value. it contiues for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and the `replace` function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  fill(action) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)
dat2
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#     user action
#    <int>  <dbl>
#  1     1      0
#  2     1      2
#  3     1      2
#  4     1      2
#  5     1      3
#  6     1      3
#  7     2      0
#  8     2      0
#  9     2      1
# 10     2      1
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "user   action
    1       NA
                  1        2
                  1       NA
                  1       NA 
                  1        3
                  1       NA
                  2       NA
                  2       NA
                  2        1
                  2       NA",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: would you please explain how it extends the value?

Comment: How can use this code for Character type rather than integer?

Comment: @Cina Not sure what you are asking. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ave` to handle the grouping and then `na.locf0` to carry forward the last occurrence of non-NA and `na.fill` to fill what is left with 0.

```
library(zoo)

transform(DF, action = na.fill(ave(action, user, FUN = na.locf0), 0))
```

giving:

```
   user action
1     1      0
2     1      2
3     1      2
4     1      2
5     1      3
6     1      3
7     2      0
8     2      0
9     2      1
10    2      1
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <- structure(list(user = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), action = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Can I use it instead for character column instead of integer?

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use `ifelse` to convert the values from NA to 0 and then use `cummax` to perform the rolling extension. `ave` will perform the grouping.

```
ave(ifelse(!is.na(dat$action), dat$action, 0), dat$user, FUN=cummax)
[1] 0 2 2 2 3 3 0 0 1 1
```

Note that this will not work if your values are not monotonically increasing.